# Android custom Overlay not drawing

Tags: android, overlay, android-maps

I am trying to draw an overlay which will show a box and text within that box but it seems not to be display.

The overlay class is shown below

```
public class StatsOverlay extends Overlay 
{
Paint paint;
double altitude;
float speed;
float distance;
float maxSpeed;
long time;
double calories;
boolean showStats;

public StatsOverlay()
{

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, Paint paint, boolean shadow)
{
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    if(showStats == true)
    {
                    paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setARGB(80, 245, 245, 245);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 350, 100, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setARGB(280, 0, 0, 0);

        canvas.drawText("Time: "+(time/60)+":"+(time%60)+"  Calories: "+calories+"  Distance: "+distance+"KM\n"+"Speed: "+speed+"KM/H   Max Speed: "+maxSpeed+"KM/H", 8, 14, paint);
    }
}

public void setStats(long time, float distance, float speed, float maxSpeed, double calories)
{
    this.time = time/1000;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.calories = calories;

}
  }
```

It never gets into the draw method at all.

This is snippet from code that calls the overlay.

```
public class Begin_Run_Map extends MapActivity implements LocationListener 
{

   //Other variables declared here for calculations

   //Overlay variables
   MyLocationOverlay myLocOver;
StatsOverlay statsOverlay;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstance)
{
    super.onCreate(savedStateInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.race_run);

            //Setting up of the mapview, initalising variables and setting up of location manager etc done here

            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.race);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mapCon = mapView.getController();



     screenOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    myLocOver = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView);
    statsOverlay = new StatsOverlay();
    screenOverlays.add(statsOverlay);
    screenOverlays.add(myLocOver);
      }
```

In the `onLocationChange(Location loc)` method is call a method `centerOnLocation(Location loc)` which passes the values to the display overlay class

```
  private void centerOnLocation(Location loc) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double lat = loc.getLatitude();
    double lng = loc.getLongitude();

    GeoPoint me = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),(int) (lng * 1E6));
    mapCon.animateTo(me);
    if(statsOverlay != null)
    {

        statsOverlay.setStats(times.get(times.size()-1), distance, avg_Speed, maxSpeed, caloriesBurned);
    }
}
```

The other overlay of MyLocationOverlay works fine as well as another overlay that shows the users previous points.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the draw function like this:

```
@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow, long when){
        super.draw(canvas, mv, shadow);
        //declare the paint object here
        Paint paint = new Paint();

}
```

Comment: It really only need the @Override part.

Comment: Yes because you are extending overlay class and want to override its draw function to your custom code.. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, just never noticed the override was missing